# Zod Validation of Both Email and Username Input

Tags: typescript, next.js, zod

I would like a method of validation of an input that has both email and username availability.

```
emailOrUsername: z.union([
    z
      .string()
      .min(1, 'Email is required')
      .email('Invalid email')
      .max(100)
      .trim(),
    z.string().min(1, 'Username is required').max(100).trim(),
  ]),
```

I tried something like the code above but this does not validate an input correctly. If you start typing the union goes on string directly, so it has no intention of checking if it's an email.

Comment: The code above DOES validate the input correctly, but your rules are not strict enough. As human we know that if the string contains "@" that is an email, but the computer does not. You need a regex for the username so it only accept certain value or when the string is without "@", it is a username.

Comment: Or you can use the zod refine() method to add custom validation logic. Doesn't look that nice, but gets the job done.